# Routing error when using Destroy in nested routes

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a strange BUG in a nested resources thing. I have a Seller/Car relationship where a Seller has_many Cars. Now I need to delete a Car from those that belong to a seller (the seller is authentication through Sessions#create and its id is stored in session[:seller_id]:

This is the Car Index View listing all cars that belong to this particular seller:

```
<%= @cars.each do |car| %>
<tr>
<td><%= car.brand %></tr></td>
<td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_seller_car_path(session[:seller_id], car) %></td>
<td><%= link_to 'Destroy', seller_car_path(session[:seller_id], car) %></td>
</tr>
<% end %>
```

Standing on the Car index listing all cars belonging to the authenticated seller, the URL looks like localhost:3000/sellers/2/cars. This page displays the table listing cars with the edit and destroy buttons (edit works fine)

Here is the Cars#destroy:

```
@seller = Seller.find(params[:seller_id])
@car = @seller.cars.find(params[:id])
@car.destroy
flash[:notice] = "Deleted"
redirect_to seller_cars_url(session[:seller_id])
```

Here is the Cars#edit (it's working fine when editing):

```
@seller  = Seller.find(params[:seller_id])
@car = @seller.cars.find(params[:id])
```

When I click on the destroy button, this BUG happens:

1) Strangely, the car is still deleted successfully.

2) I get routing error:

```
No route matches {:action => "edit", :controller => "cars", :seller_id=>nil, id=>#<Car id:23, brand:"Opel"...
```

Looks like the problem here arises in the Edit button in the index page. The car it's referring to is the first car in the table and the seller_id is nil here, meaning the seller_id is no longer held in session[:seller_id], which is the act of Sessions#destroy

3) I noticed that the Seller is logged out. As if the destroy in Car controller invokes the Destroy in Sessions controller that clears the session.

4) The URL seems to be the correct one for the Cars index: localhost:3000/sellers/2/cars, but I still see that routing error mentioned in 2.

I would appreciate if you please help guide me in this strange behavior. Thank you.

Comment: Try to redirect to `seller_cars_path` instead of `seller_cars_url` in the `Cars#destroy`. There are possible some mismatching in the config, and `redirect_to` `*_url` leads to another domain (so the cookies get lost)

Comment: Thank you dimcuh for your assistance!!! I am no longer now getting the routing error after using seller_cars_path as you suggested. However, still the strange thing of logging out the user. It redirects to localhost:3000/sellers with user signed out. This is strange. I can't find a reason for this other than suspecting that it call Sessions#destroy with Cars#destroy. I am not sure if these two lines cause this:@seller = Seller.find(params[:seller_id])
@car = @seller.cars.find(params[:id])